# Вывод изображеня

Tags: php

Вопрос: отображаются непонятные иероглифы при выводе картинки.
Как это можно исправить?
Пишет ошибка: header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

```
$filename = 'Pk.jpg';

// тип содержимого
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// получение нового размера
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);

if($width>150){
    $diff = $width-150;
    $percnt_reduced = (($diff/$width)*100);
    $new_height = $height-(($percnt_reduced*$height)/100);
   // $wd= $width-$diff;
}
if($height>150){
    $diff = $height-150;
    $percnt_reduced = (($diff/$height)*100);
    $new_width = $width-(($percnt_reduced*$width)/100);
 //   $ht= $height-$diff;
}

$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

// изменение размера
imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
// вывод
```

Answer (score 3):

Я так понял, что вы header поставили после какого-то вывода. Соответственно, и не срабатывает, выводит кодированный формат. **Никакого вывода на страницу перед header() быть не должно!**

Answer (score 1):

А почему 2 раза header?

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

$filename = 'Pk.jpg';

// тип содержимого
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```

Попробуйте еще добавить header Content-Length и не забывайте про imagedestroy();

Создайте HTML страницу с тэгом img и ссылкой на ваш скрипт, если картинка появится, значит дело в header, если нет - надо искать...

Comment: нет, он один рас первый опичатка

Comment: @Fairlooli, пишите, пожалуйста, грамотней.

Comment: Попробуйте еще добавить header Content-Length